# Is there a maximum speed on Subway Surfers?

Tags: subway-surfers

I believe that at some point in the Subway Surfers, while running, you reach a maximum speed. Things will no longer come at you with increased speed. Is there a certain amount of time or a certain score where this happens at? Does it even happen at all?

I find the game getting boring at ~500-600K score, because it doesn't seem to get any harder. Hence the reason why I am asking the following:

Does anyone know **if** and **at what point in time**/**at what score** this top-speed is reached?

Answer (score 2):

In later stages, around 500-600k as you mentioned it stays at the same pace. I don't know the exact number but yes there is a max speed. If you use the hover board that's also a rocket, it gives you a speed increase which will make things faster but only for the duration. I've made it to 2.3 million and the speed is the same as it was back at 500k. If I were to guess, I would say around 200-300k it gets up there or pretty close too then, doesn't increase after that.

Comment: guesses aren't really what I'm looking for

Comment: The only way you can know the exact score for the cap would be to some how access the program files and find the line of code related to the speed (probably a multiplier based on score) and then figure out the cap number. Something like "if the score is equal to say 200k or more, speed is equal to cap speed"

Comment: there are ways to do that, so there is a definite answer instead of guesses

Comment: I'm saying that you can hit the cap at different scores based on how far you've traveled and how many coins you've hit as well as how many power-ups you hit. I'm looking into it but I'm just letting you know that there may not be a definite answer and this is also a gaming community with opinions from players, not app developers. Going into program files to find a speed equation is no small task.